# Массовое автоформатирование php кода в стиле PEAR

Tags: style, php

Добрый вечер, люди добрые.

Подскажите, как можно осуществить массовое автоформатирование кода в стиле PEAR. Мне достался довольно-таки страшный проект без отсуствия отступов. Хочется привести его в читабельный вид. В качестве IDE использую простенький Notepad++. Нашел под него плагин, но вот наладить не смог его.

Спасибо.

Comment: > проект без отсуствия отступов.

Т.е. отступы уже есть :)

Comment: Попробуйте [CS Fixer](https://github.com/fabpot/PHP-CS-Fixer).

Comment: PHPStorm, там есть функция формативарония кода всего проекта или отдельных файлов.

Comment: >IDE использую простенький Notepad++

Щито??? Выкиньте его, только PHPStorm, вот это настоящая IDE. А Notepad++ это текстовый редактор, то, что он подсвечивает код, не делает его IDE.

Comment: @Данис Гиламов, для этих целей лучше поставить какую-нить IDE - там есть кнопочка, которая сделает всю работу за вас (главное указать в каком виде вы это хотите видеть)

@ua6xh, я несколько раз честно пытался освоить какую-нить IDE, но через полчаса-час бросал это дело и возвращался к своему npp ) Практически все, что мне нужно, там есть. Чего нет - есть IDE, в которой это можно сделать. Т.е. IDE включаю только когда надо проверить чужой код на синтаксические ошибки и code style. В прошлом году включал раза 4, в этом еще ни разу.

Здесь дело вкуса, иногда вообще в mc пишу, а в npp переношу ))

Comment: @BOPOH, с какими фреймворками вы работали? Вы пишите тесты? Вы используете гит? Вы используете phpDoc и todo? Вы имеет опыт рефакторинга? Вы используете парадигму ООП?

Comment: @ua6xh, немного с Silex, достаточно с Zend, чуть-чуть еще с Wordpress работал + не одна сотня тысяч строк нескольких приложений на Zend`е и нативном PHP (это если бранчи для заказчиков еще не считать)

Уже почти три года так работаю - пока не жаловался )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поставь себе [IDE PHPStorm](http://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/download/).

В настройках проекта найди [Code Style](http://take.ms/lAF0e) и настрой, как тебе надо.

Затем открой проект или директорию с файлами и в дереве файлов выбери [корень проекта](http://take.ms/IJMkE).

Затем в меню выбери [Code/Reformat Code](http://take.ms/QGP4X).